# RestKit 0.20.0-rc1 - Duplicate object after POST

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, restkit

I'm running into an issue while trying to synchronize a list of favourited teams for a given user between my iOS app and my server. The flow of events is as follows:

1. User favourites a team
2. New favouriteTeam object is created and saved to Core Data:

   NSError *error;
   [[self.currentUser managedObjectContext] save:&error];
   [[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].persistentStoreManagedObjectContext save:&error];
3. Array of modified favouriteTeams is POSTed to the server where they are timestamped and returned with any other modified or recently added (by another device) objects.
4. The problem I'm running into is that the item that is POSTed, since it is always returned is being duplicated instead of being overwritten (based on the identificationAttributes). None of the other objects returned (whether modified or newly created by another device) get duplicated... just the newly created device from the user's device.

Here's my Request/Response mapping code:

```
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
[objectManager setRequestSerializationMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];
// POST Request Mapping
RKObjectMapping *favouriteTeamMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[favouriteTeamMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"uuid", @"teamName", @"displayOrder"]];
RKRequestDescriptor *favouriteTeamRequestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:favouriteTeamMapping objectClass:[FavouriteTeam class] rootKeyPath:@"favouriteTeams"];
[objectManager addRequestDescriptor:favouriteTeamRequestDescriptor];
// Response Mapping
RKEntityMapping *favouriteTeamResponseMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"FavouriteTeam" inManagedObjectStore:objectManager.managedObjectStore];
favouriteTeamResponseMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"uuid"];
[favouriteTeamResponseMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"uuid", @"teamName", @"displayOrder", @"lastModified"]];
RKResponseDescriptor *favouriteTeamResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:favouriteTeamResponseMapping pathPattern:@"/api/favouriteteam/" keyPath:@"data.favouriteTeams" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
[objectManager addResponseDescriptorsFromArray:@[favouriteTeamResponseDescriptor]];
// POST
[objectManager postObject:favTeamsArray path:@"/api/favouriteteam/" parameters:nil success:nil failure:nil];
```

I can't seem to figure out why this duplication is happening when the identificationAttributes (favouriteDrug "uuid" attribute) are set. The objects are identical (even the same uuid) in Core Data. What is causing this behaviour?

**NOTE:** This question is also posted on the RestKit Google Groups [here.](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!starred/restkit/cmNUdWrJOao)

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** It appears that this duplication doesn't occur the first time a team is favorited. Any of the following attempts to favorite a team result in this duplication.

Comment: did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Yes & No. I ended up not using RestKit and doing it manually with AFNetworking.

Comment: I solved this, will post answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and while I cannot really confirm if this addressed your problem, will post my answer here anyways.

My problem was that the first object would be created fine, but thereafter restkit would save duplicate objects in coredata, so this sounds like the problem you are seeing.

I was making the post call to create object by:
* creating a blank object in coredata and filling it with whatever attributes I need
* make a post call to server using restkit API and passing in the newly created object

What restkit does under the hood is to take the response, fill it into the new object I created, and save it into coredata WITHOUT checking if there is another object of the same unique id beforehand.  This is why the first object creation was fine, but subsequent objects were duplicates.

The way I solved it was actually to pass in the raw values as params to the restkit post API call, and nil as the object.  On the reply, restkit will then look through coredata first to see if an object of that ID exists and merge changes with that object, or create a new one.